# batch file pinging an ip address and a text file showing the lower min/average/higher max

Tags: file, batch-file, response, ping, average

Is there a way of pinging an ip address continually and printing a text file showing just the lower min/average/higher max ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ping with the `-t` option. It will ping continuously. At any point you can press `<Ctrl-Break>` to see the statistics, including min/avg/max. Press `<Ctrl-C>` to quit.